# problems with c pointer strings

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, strlen

:)
I'm trying to beat string pointers in c, so I write this code but I didn't get the result that I expected.

I'm creating a string variable, and I want to pass it to a function that check if the string lenght is bigger than 10.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
bool is_bigger_than_10(char *);

int main()
{
    char *string1 = "";
    int i = 0;
    printf("Initial string: %s\n",&string1);
    printf("Size is: %d\n",strlen(&string1));
    printf("Give me one string: ");
    scanf("%[^\t\n]s",&string1);  //This scan allows me to enter string with spaces

    printf("You write: %s\n", &string1);
    printf("Size is: %d\n",strlen(&string1));
    printf("String character by character:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(&string1) ; i++)
    {
        printf("%c ",&string1[i]);
    }

    printf("\nNow let's check if it's bigger than 10\n");
    printf("Answer is: %d",is_bigger_than_10(&string1));

    return 0;
}

bool is_bigger_than_10(char *textx)
{
    printf("%s --> %d > %d\n",&textx, strlen(&textx),10);
    if(strlen(&textx) > 10)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The expected output should be:

Initial string:
Size is 0:
Give me one string: axel
You write: axel
String character by character:
a x e l
Now let's check if it's bigger than 10
a x e l --> 4 > 10
Answer is: 0

If yoy run that code and enter **axel** as the input string you will get this:

Initial string: $0@
Size is 3:
Give me one string: axel
You write: axel
String character by character: a b c d e
a x e l
Now let's check if it's bigger than 10
 '  --> 3 > 10
Answer is: 0

It's kind of weird, could some one help me to correct this code?

Comment: If you turn on warnings, you should get a lot of them concerning your over-use of the `&` operator.

Comment: Your strings are arrays and therefore pointers, so you don't need to use their addresses in referring to them for printf etc.

Comment: @MandyShaw -- arrays are not pointers; array identifiers _decay_ to pointers to the first element of their associated arrays in most expressions (in function calls, for example), but arrays are objects in and of themselves in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things going on here:

First, your char pointer needs to point somewhere. With the line

```
char *string1 = "";
```

you create a pointer to a string literal, which you can't write to. (Obviously you can, given your output, but you just got lucky on a system that allows it.) Create a character buffer instead:

```
char string1[200] = "";
```

and ideally enforce the constant buffer limit when you read the string.

Second, you don't need all these `&`s. The `&` is not a magic marker that you have to prepend to all your arguments.

The `&` takes the address of a variable and passes it as a pointer. You need that when the called function needs to change the variable via the pointer. Printing doesn't need to change anything, so unless you want to print the address of a variable with `%p`, you shouldn't pass addresses. (In the special case of your program, you can just remove all ampersands with search and replace.)

When scanning, you need to change variables if you convert input to numbers or if you scan a char. The exception is when you scan strings with `%s`or `%[...]`: Here, you pass a char buffer (as a pointer to its first elements) and the function then fills that buffer.

The problem with `scanf` and `printf` is that the arguments after the format string are variadic, which means they will accept any arguments without type checking. The good thing is that most compilers can tell whether a format string matches the arguments and will issue warnings, it you enable them. Do yourself a favour and do that.

(Warnings will also tell you that you have type mismatches in functions where the type of the argument is known, such as your `is_bigger_than_10`.)